# Use Python logging to determine where a method was called from

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm trying to debug a Python Django app.

I've got additional fields being added to a model.

I've tracked this down to one method:
django.db.models.options.add_field()

The only place this method is called is:
django.db.models.fields.**init**.contribute_to_class()

```
def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
  self.set_attributes_from_name(name)
  cls._meta.add_field(self)
  if self.choices:
    setattr(cls, 'get_%s_display' % self.name, curry(cls._get_FIELD_display, field=self))
```

I'm trying to use Logging to determine where the additions to the User model are occurring.

Is there anyway to that I can set a logging message that will record where this contribute_to_class() method was called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module.